# Redis cache conflicts with Prometheus

Tags: java, maven, prometheus, quarkus

I'm trying to add Redis cache to my Quarkus project, and I faced an issue where the application fails to start when I combine the **quarkus-redis-cache** and **quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus** simultaneously.

Can someone help with it?

```
  <dependencies>
    <!--Quarkus-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Issue -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-redis-cache</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Issue -->
  </dependencies>
```

**the startup error:**

```
WARN  [io.net.uti.con.DefaultPromise] (vert.x-acceptor-thread-0) An exception was thrown by io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase$$Lambda$1193/0x000002b439709ec0.operationComplete(): java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpBinderConfiguration was not found
    at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.VertxMeterBinderAdapter.createHttpServerMetrics(VertxMeterBinderAdapter.java:63)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.createMetrics(HttpServerImpl.java:73)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase.lambda$null$3(TCPServerBase.java:244)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:97)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.AsyncResolveConnectHelper.lambda$null$1(AsyncResolveConnectHelper.java:61)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:578)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasksFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:426)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:375)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:557)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**application.yml**

```
    quarkus:
      http:
        port: 8181
      redis:
        devservices:
          enabled: true
      micrometer:
        export:
          prometheus:
            enabled: true
            path: /metrics
```

I've tryed to change versions to 3.3.0, 3.6.0

Comment: I tried this and could not reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, the solution is to have Docker launched

Comment: looks good that solved your problem